# I'm migrating an opencart webshop from one server to another and I keep getting fatal errors

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart, fatal-error

I really can't find anything about this problem on the internet and as I am no PHP programmer I decided to ask you guys...

I am migrating an opencart webshop from one server to another. I have made a clean install of opencart, used clean config.php and admin/config.php files, transferred the webshop via FTP (minus the config.php files) created a new database, emptied it, updated the mysql database, imported all sql files (with the help from phpmyadmin).

Also I placed everything in the public_html directory on my server, but I keep getting error messages.

At first I got an error saying it can't find xxx.oc_store table, I fixed that problem after completely renewing the database.

now I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/index.php on line 19
```

my config.php files look like this accordingly:

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.langvanstof.nl/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.langvanstof.nl/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', '<USERNSAME>');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '<PASSWORD>>');
define('DB_DATABASE', '<DBNAME>');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
?>
```

I took away the / before home
it was like this:

```
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/system/logs/');
```

Can anyone help me with this problem,because it's driving me nuts haha 
I do have one guess though... I think it has something to do with vqmod that is isn't functioning properly, but then again I am a noob and no programmer so I could be wrong.

The link to the website is http://www.langvanstof.nl
If needed I can provide more information.

Kind Regards,

Jean-Phillippe Wijnholds

Comment: Why did you took away `/` before home? Without it path is relative to current working directory. Can you show current working directory with `var_dump(getcwd())` ?

Comment: piotrekkr is correct, you need to add the `/` back and make sure the paths are all correct and that you've set up the correct permissions

Comment: I took them away, because it was offered as a solution on a different website I do have the original config.php files so I can check if it works

Comment: after changing it back I got the following error Error: Could not load database file mysqli!

Comment: using the var_dump(getcwd()) code doesnt do anything... probably not using it right though

Answer (score 1):

Though You didn't tell us the version of OpenCart You are installing and though it is probable You do not have OC 1.5.6.1 installed which only fully supports MySQLi, I recommend to change in Your configs this line:

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
```

to

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
// mind the 'i' missing  ^^^
```

of course while preserving those `/` in the beginning of each path.

Comment: THe version i use is 1.5.1.3.1 because the webshop was originally written in that version. I already changed it from mysqli to mysql 
still i get the following error: 
Notice: Error: Table 'karpetten_stofnl.oc_store' doesn't exist
Error No: 1146
SELECT * FROM oc_store WHERE REPLACE(`url`, 'www.', '') = 'http://langvanstof.nl/' in /home/karpetten/domains/langvanstof.nl/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 49

Comment: Are You sure You are connecting to a correct database? If You log into Your phpMyAdmin and select that database, can You see all the tables (as well as table `oc_store`)? Isn't it possible that Your tables are created without the `oc_` prefix?

Comment: the strange thing is, i have done several installs now, and sometimes it does show the oc_Store table, sometimes it doesn't. 
and somehow it does make tables with and without the prefix, some even include toc_ prefix, I tried to change the database prefix to toc_ but it didnt have any effect

Comment: You are selecting the DB tables prefix during the install when providing the database connection details (I guess last step in install process before it is installed). If You leave the DB prefix field empty, the table names would have no prefixes at all. However Your settings should mirror this in config.php files.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server support mysqli driver ? , change it to mysql in config it may be work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you changing it to mysql instead of mysqli. 1.5.6.1 supports mysqli but your database was not created for that. Your fallback would be to keep it as it is than to change it.

Why don't you clone the entire directory from your old server to the new one, while only changing the location of your config files? It works even better this way.

Answer (score 0):

> I would recommend you changing it to mysql instead of mysqli. 1.5.6.1
>   supports mysqli but your database was not created for that. Your
>   fallback would be to keep it as it is than to change it.
>
> Why don't you clone the entire directory from your old server to the
>   new one, while only changing the location of your config files? It
>   works even better this way.

Thanks! after cloning the directory and editing the config files, I have got it up and running.

My solution: when migrating an opencart webshop to another server:

Install both PHPmyadmin and the version of opencart that has been used in the development of the webshop. (In my case it was version 1.5.1.3.1)

after completing the installation of opencart save the config.php files to your harddrive and compare them to the the config.php files in the original directory.

make sure you change the database prefix if needed and change the login codes for the database you are going to use.

Mostly you will need to edit the pathways to the database.

After cloning the original directory with the edited config.php files to your server, 
run phpmyadmin, empty all the tables in your database and import the sql file of the database.

And presto! the webshop has migrated!